# What happens when I rename a file with a directory name in same folder?

Tags: linux, terminal, mv

I accidentally did just this. I just typed
`mv .vimrc .vim`
in my home directory.
`.vimrc` was a file
`.vim` is a directory

Did it just disappear? I do have a backup of my .vimrc but it is a little old. Is there a way to recover it the way it was?

Maybe I should have updated my backup, maybe I should have used that confirmation flag for the mv. In fact, both. But it happened ):

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You moved `.vimrc` **inside** the `.vim` directory. In other words, you can find the file at `.vim/.vimrc`.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, but I really did not. I looked inside .vim first thing.
To move it I should have written ` .vimrc .vim/`, with a slash, I believe
):

Comment: @Periiz No, you don't need the trailing `/`. Note that `.vimrc` is a hidden file, so it won't show up with a normal `ls`. You'll have to use `ls -a .vim`.

Comment: Ooooh I just found out what I did. I wasn't at my home directory (omg I'm so dumb). I'm very ashamed right now.
I was at somewhere else, so my .vimrc was renamed to .vim inside this other directory.
I just checked the history. The command was actually `mv ~/.vimrc .vim`
Thanks for the patience, and sorry for this. I feel like deleting this post if it is possible @.@